# GetElementById Returning Null In IE

Tags: javascript

In the function below chld is null only in IE, in firefox the javascript works fine.

```
    var div = document.createElement("div");

    var divid = "dv" + num;

    div.setAttribute("ID", divid);

    div.setAttribute("value", num);



    var _text = document.createElement("input");

    _text.setAttribute("type", "text");

    _text.setAttribute("id", "txtAsName" + num);



    _text.setAttribute("name", "txtAsName" + num);


    var lbl = document.createElement("label");




    var _upload = document.createElement("input");

    _upload.setAttribute("type", "file");

    _upload.setAttribute("ID", "upload" + num);



    _upload.setAttribute("name", "uploads" + num);

    _upload.setAttribute("size", "80");



    var hyp = document.createElement("a");

    //hyp.setAttribute("style", "cursor:Pointer");
    hyp.style.cssText='cursor:Pointer';

    //hyp.setAttribute("onclick", "return RemoveDv('" + divid + "');");
    hyp.onclick=function() {RemoveDv(divid);};

    hyp.innerHTML = "Remove";



    var br = document.createElement("br");

    var _pdiv = document.getElementById("Parent");

    div.appendChild(br);

    div.appendChild(lbl);

    div.innerHTML += ' ';

    div.appendChild(_text);

    div.innerHTML += ' ';

    div.appendChild(_upload);

    div.innerHTML += ' ';

    div.appendChild(hyp);

    _pdiv.appendChild(div);
```

....

Here is the remove function

```
 function RemoveDv(obj) {

        var p = document.getElementById("Parent");

        var chld = document.getElementById(obj);


        p.removeChild(chld);

    }
```

Here is what the div tags look lie that I am trying to remove..

```
<div align="left" id="Parent">
    <div ID="dv1" value="1">
<div ID="dv2" value="2">
```

....

Interestingly even when I add this line of code "for debug sake" chld1 is still null

```
var chld1 = document.getElementById("dv1");
```

UPDATE:

It seems that there is nothing wrong with the code itself. If I run the same code in ie off my local code chld gets set. But if I run this code off our dev server ie does not see the element.

Any ideas why this could be?

Comment: How are you calling your function?  Where is the "Parent" element?

Comment: @user295734: Simple things like this do certainly not require jQuery.

Comment: obj is "dv1" and all the div tags are found in a div tag called "Parent"

Comment: Maybe you could add the actual call to your original post?

Comment: Well, there is nothing wrong with the code you posted, so the problem must be somewhere else. Maybe you can create a http://jsfiddle.net/ demo. You can improve the code though: `chld.parentNode.removeChild(chld)`. No need to get a reference to parent first.

Comment: post more complete code, dude. btw, what is "value" attribute on your div for?

Comment: @felix i was seeing if he already was using it, cause it would be alot simpler then using parentnodes and removechilds. Its want jquery was meant to do, to avoid browser trouble trying to navigate the dom.

Comment: "chld" is null when I click a hyperlink and this only happens in IE but works in firefox

Comment: Check which value `obj` has when the handler is executed. Are you certain that `chld` is `null`?

Comment: Try using "dv1" instead of obj for debugging's sake. Also, make sure the divs are loaded before the function is called.

Comment: yes ie says "WebPage Error" asks me if I would like to debug and in there I AddWatch and can see the "chld" variable gets set to null. This all works in firefox

Comment: @septerr it seems that for some reason eventhough I can see the div tags in the the Parent div via developer tools they are not being loaded because var chld1 = document.getElementById("dv1");
returns null as well

Comment: This is a long shot, but try changing the capital case ID attribute on the div to lower case id. I don't have IE and can't test this out myself right now...sorry.

Comment: It seems that there is nothing wrong with the code itself. If I run the same code in ie off my local code chld gets set. But if I run this code off our dev server ie does not see the element.

Any ideas why this could be?

Comment: Does your code get embedded inside some other HTML on the server? Some kind of caching issue (I doubt that since you are looking the code in debug tools and would know if it didn't look like latest)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a long shot, but try changing the capital case ID attribute on the div to lower case id. I don't have IE and can't test this out myself right now...sorry

Answer (score 1):

If you have multiple elements with same `ID` in the DOM, `document.getElementById` function in Internet explorer returns null and in Firefox it is returning the first found object.

please check your code to make sure that only one element with `id` "Parent" exists on the page

Comment: There is only 1 "Parent" and 1 "dv1" found in the entire html

Comment: It seems that there is nothing wrong with the code itself. If I run the same code in ie off my local code chld gets set. But if I run this code off our dev server ie does not see the element.

Any ideas why this could be?

Comment: the code works on my machine IE8 and FF13

Answer (score 0):

You could simple save a reference and delete the nodes without to search them.